# Java EE: Where could I read about dao, services and why they're used?

Tags: java, service, dao

Ok
I'm new at my job, and now I'm assigned to a project which uses Spring, Hibernate and Wicket.
And I see a lot of DAO and Services packages and I want to understand why they're used and what is advantajes of this.

I understand that DAO it's need for working with the databases, but I want more information.

I need an overall, a BIG PICTURE of DAO and Services layers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls2/). This book explains all essential aspects of Spring, DAOs and services.

Answer (score 0):

So the services are set up as the API to your application. Usually this is referred to as the service layer in a N-Tiered application. The Data Access Object layer is set up to provide business rules and access to the persistent data your application will store and access. The DAO's typically store the data in a database but can also persist it in other ways. Here are some suggestions for more details on this overview:

- [Baeldung - Spring Persistence Tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/persistence-with-spring-series/)
- [JavaCodeGeeks - One Good Think](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/02/one-thing-good-spring-developers-know.html)
- [Spring - Data Access with JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)
- [Stackoverflow question - Responsibilities and use of Service & Dao layers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13785970/3368958)

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) ... please don't do the same undesirable thing as the other, very old answers.

Comment: I disagree! The question asked WHERE can I learn, it did not say "explain to me". The reference you make even lists this as an exception to your tag - "Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick."

Comment: *"Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer"* (quote from the provided link) ...you know what this means, right?

Comment: Right I read the article provided in the link. And it states the exception to the "Not an Answer" rule is when the question actually states suggest tutorials where I can learn. It states this half way down in the article. This question asked where to look for information. That's what I and the others provided. Then I also question why you waited 6 years to flag it??

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress The correct thing would be to flag the question for closure as it is currently off-topic. That's what the help center says to avoid answering off topic questions.