# Is there a way to call method after contractor after deserializion

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I deserialize a json and want then to call postProcess method by annotation or another way after constractor?

json file:

```
{
  "type": "storeType",
  "name": "store-name",
  "list": [
    {
      "type": "itemType",
      "name": "item1-name",
    },
    {
      "type": "itemType",
      "name": "item2-name",
    }
  ]
}
```

Store.class:

```
 Store extends AbstractClass{

    @Value("${store.size:100000}")
    private Integer size;
    @Autowired
    private StorePersistency persistency;

    private String name;
    private List<abstractClass> list;

    public Store(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("list") list) {
        this.name=name;
        this.list=list;
    }

   @Override
   public postProcess(){
     ...
   }
}
```

Item.class:

```
 Item extends AbstractClass{

    private String name;

    public Store(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

   @Override
   public postProcess(){
     ...
   }
}
```

deserializerService:

```
AbstractClass clzz = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, AbstractClass.class)
```

The purpose is to @authowire and @value other class fields (StorePersistency 
 and size) by calling a authowireService in postProcess method.

AuthowireService:

```
public void authowireBean(Class clzz){
   applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(clzz, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
}
```

Comment: you should just create own json deserializer for such class, to get rid of all the other beans from it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely decouple `POJO` from persistence and service layers. For persistence layer you could use [DAO pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern) which is probably represented by `StorePersistency` class in your case. You need to create service layer which implement `postProcess`. See [Responsibilities and use of Service and DAO Layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785634/responsibilities-and-use-of-service-and-dao-layers) for more info. Example service layer in your case could look like below:

```
@Component
class StoreService {

    @Value("${store.size:100000}")
    private Integer size;

    @Autowired
    private StorePersistency persistency;

    public postProcess(Store store) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use the StorePersistency  and size and maybe more other beans (that not related to store) at the same Store.class, which I use for json deserialization..

Comment: @MariaDorohin, if beans are not related with `Store` class they should not be injected to `Store` class. Probably you have some actions to implement which do something with `Store`. You can implement [Command Pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-command-pattern) and create many `CommandStore1`, `CommandStore2` and inject whatever you need there.